# Sql, Advance Design help

Tags: mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Statement to write table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556064/sql-statement-to-write-table)

1) Consider the social network below. In this network nodes represent person and links represents friendships. For example, A and B are friends, and there is a link between A and B. You want to have a database to store your user profiles (id, fname, lname, email, gender, password-you can use node node names as ids), and users’s interests (a person can have multiple interests), and their friendship connections

so far i have only part of the sql statement done. i need help with the relationships

```
drop table users;
drop table intrest;
drop table friendships;

create table users(
id INT,
Fname char(15),
Lname char(15),
email char(20),
street char(15),
state char(2),
zip INT,
age INT,
gender char (2),
phone INT,
User_password char(15),
primary key (id)

create table Instrests(
id INT,
description char(30),
Primary key (id),
foreign key (users_id) 

create table friendships(
```

Comment: It's a little sad that there are users, but no friendships... :-(

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556064/sql-statement-to-write-table, although phrased a bit better.

Comment: LOL @ "i need help with the relationships". Don't we all =(

Answer (score 1):

Btw there is a much better way to represent your data, upload a image (save you so much time if you screen dump the table struc and post on here) also I already have a post asking about relationships this was my output after some help.

[image]

Notice the friendships between User and Friends and the sql syntax is like so:

```
select 
    u2.UserID,
    u2.FirstName,
    u2.SecondName,
    p.picturepath
from User u1 -- This gets me
join Friends f on u1.UserID = f.UserID -- This gets my friends
join User u2 on f.FriendID = u2.UserID -- This gets my friends info
join Pictures p on p.UserID = u2.UserID -- This gets my friends pics
where u1.UserID = 1  -- ...or whatever; don't actually hardcode "1"!
```

Now all you have to do is take this and apply it as such for your own method.

Comment: A friend should only be a friend when both parties agree on that. How's that caught? A-B + B-A > friends?

Comment: I'd also say that having an ID in this case is totally unnecessary. Now you've got 4 indexes (mysql requires indexes on foreign keys) to maintain, one of which is useless. Just use a compound primary key, removes the useless `PK` and converts the `UNIQUE` to a `PK` (it's a natural key...). Also, inline with Rudie's comment, I'd call it connections and search for a pair in order to be friends.

Comment: Hey Rudie, yup your correct all you would have to do its set another field in the friends table and call it flag, do some coding to send a message to the user that you have a pending friend request and as soon as he clicks accept set the flag to 0 again. Easy!

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
friendships
------------
user_1_id
user_2_id
status
```